# Error 255 when sharing folder on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, permissions, shared-folders, sharing

I try to share folder on Ubuntu, the steps I did:

Right click on folder

I clicked **sharing options**

Then I clicked **share this folder**

Then I clicked **create share**

I got this message :'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot share path..
[image]

How to fix this .

Comment: I had this issue when I tried to add a usershare before samba was installed `apt install samba`

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution would to be to add the stated lines,

> usershare owner only = false

to the Global section of the smb.conf file by,

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

then save the file and restart the samba service,

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Then try again to share the selected folder

Answer (score 1):

Open the parent directory with administrator permission and try again

```
sudo apt-get install gksu

gksu nautilus /your_complete_path/
```

then share the folder...

Comment: Wow. Just wow. All my 3+ years of searching for an out-of-the-box Samba share solution! The problem? I had to run as root. Shame on you Linux Mint, shame.